# Array_diff not taking in arguments

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, array-difference

I am trying to get the difference of two files:

```
$first = file('lalala.json');
$second = file('alabala.json');
//print_r($first);
//print_r($second);
$first_result = array_diff($first[0], $second[0]);
//$second_result = array_diff($second, $first);
print_r($first_result);
//print_r($second_result);
```

The content of `lalala.json` is:

```
`[{"name":"Tim Pearson","id":"17118"},{"name":"Ashley Danchen Chen","id":"504829084"},{"name":"Foisor Veronica","id":"100005485446135"}]`
```

while the content of `alabala.json` is

```
 `[{"name":"Tim Pearson","id":"17118"},{"name":"Foisor Veronica","id":"100005485446135"}]`
```

However the problem is that I get an error, because the content will not be recognised as an array (the error is `Argument #1 is not an array`). If I do `array_diff($first, $second)` the output will be the content of `$first` which is

```
Array ( [0] => [{"name":"Tim Pearson","id":"17118"},{"name":"Ashley Danchen Chen","id":"504829084"},{"name":"Foisor Veronica","id":"100005485446135"}] )
```

How should I handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert the JSON objects to arrays first and then find the difference between the two arrays. To convert a JSON string into an array use [`json_decode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) with `true` as second parameter:

```
$firstArray = json_decode($first, true);
```

If you leave the second parameter out, $firstArray would be an object, that is an instance of `stdClass`.

But first you'd need the content of the file as a string, so better use [`file_get_contents()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php):

```
$first = file_get_contents('lalala.json');
```

**Update:**
Even when you've converted the JSON strings properly into array, you'll still have a problem, as [`array_diff()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) only works with one dimensional arrays, as it's mentioned in the `Notes` section of the documentation. To be able to use in on multidimensional arrays, have a look at [this comment](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php#37527) to the documentation.

Comment: It will convert the string to array instead of an object (instance of stdClass)

Comment: But now for some reason, the output is an empty array

Comment: Did you switch from `file` to `file_get_contents` before using `json_decode`?

Comment: Any errors? BTW, if you'd copy/pasted my code from above, I just realised I've misspelled the name...

Comment: The content of first_array is `Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => Tim Pearson [id] => 17118 ) [1] => Array ( [name] => Ashley Danchen Chen [id] => 504829084 ) [2] => Array ( [name] => Foisor Veronica [id] => 100005485446135 ) ) `

Comment: So, you meant the output of `array_diff`? The first argument should be the longer array, the array to compare from. Is that so in your code?

Comment: yes, it is. I have tried both putting $first_array first and then putting $second_array first, and in both cases, the output of the array_diff is `Array()`

Comment: Oh, that's going to be really bad.. The answer to my question is corect, thanks. But I will create another post, because it's a little bit more complicated. This particular example was simple, but I might have files encoded at different depths.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You probably mean

```
$first = json_decode(file_get_contents('lalala.json'), true);
$second = json_decode(file_get_contents('alabala.json'), true);
```